# Service working via Cluster-IP, but not via Ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I need help figuring out what I'm doing wrong with my Ingress setup Minikube/ingress-nginx-controller. Kubectl version is 1.19. Minikube version is 1.13.1

I have 2 services: 1 that I created from an image I built myself in dotnetcore and another that I pulled from an example. The example is giving me no problems: I can reach it via `http://myapp.com/web`. The one I built can be reached directly via its Cluster IP (port 80) in the browser, but can't be reached from the browser using `http://myapp.com/datasvc` (404 error). Here's a snippet from my Ingress yaml:

```
- host: myapp.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /web2 #works
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web2
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /datasvc
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: datasvc
            port:
              number: 80
```

And here's what my backends look like:

```
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  myapp.com
              /web2       web2:8080     172.17.0.7:8080)
              /datasvc   datasvc:80   172.17.0.8:80)
```

Services:

```
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
datasvc                 ClusterIP      10.100.7.119    <none>          80/TCP           11hde here
web2                    NodePort       10.98.6.48      <none>          8080:31122/TCP   12h
```

CURL output from `curl -H "HOST: myapp.com" localhost/web2 -v`:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /web2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: myapp.com    
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.19.1
< Date: Sun, 04 Oct 2020 16:16:55 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 61
< Connection: keep-alive
<
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web2-7d85fb54bf-f26p2
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

CURL output from `curl -H "HOST: myapp.com" localhost/datasvc -v`

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /datasvc HTTP/1.1
> Host: myapp.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.19.1
< Date: Sun, 04 Oct 2020 16:20:13 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The only difference I can see between the 2 is the fact that the example (web2) service uses `type: NodePort` and mine uses the default (`type: ClusterIP`). I tried doing the same with my service, but that made no difference.

I don't know what else to look at diagnostically or where to go from here. I've checked out many Medium posts but haven't come across anything that describes my situation. Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ingress [supports either](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) `NodePort` service type or `LoadBalancer`. `ClusterIP` service will be available only inside minikube VM.

For minikube you should use [NodePort service type configuration](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service). To setup ingress on minikube you can follow [official documentation](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/).

To expose your deployment you can use kubectl:

```
kubectl expose deployment <deployment_name> --type=NodePort --port=<port_number>
```

To check if service is correctly working you can run `minikube service list` and curl URL that you have exposed.

If everything is working correctly you can setup your ingress and add `IP Address` and `HOST` to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As it turned out, my setup was close to working, but my service uses routes within my REST API. I should have been trying `localhost/datasvc/data` instead of `localhost/datasvc`.